# How can I say "May I have your attention, please?" in fewer words

Tags: expressions

How can I draw the attention of a group of people who are chit-chatting but in fewer words? Or what are other alternatives apart from "May I have your attention, please?"?

In my mother tongue (Kinyarwanda) there's an expression that goes like "ndasaba ijambo" which literally translates " I'm asking to be allowed to speak" which I thought is a bit more clear when one says "May I get your attention please" but still it doesn't sound to be the "right" translation of that expression (from Kinyarwanda)

Comment: shouting "oye" works quite well

Comment: @WendyG that's quite informal, isn't it? I would like something a bit formal. But thanks anyway

Comment: why do you want less words than the standard phrase?  why is this important? it takes quite a while to write a good answer for this site people expect you to have done some work yourself.

Comment: "Hey!!!" should do it.

Comment: well, thank you @WendyG. In my mother tongue (Kinyarwanda) there's an expression that goes like "ndasaba ijambo" which literally translates  " I'm asking to be allowed to speak" which I thought is a bit more clear when one says "May I get your attention please" but still it doesn't sound to be the "right" translation of that expression (from Kinyarwanda)

Comment: @NtwariPrinceJr. If you want something formal that means “I ask asking to be allowed to speak”, consider “May I have the floor?”. It’s no shorter, but it’s used in formal contexts like meetings or panels. “The floor” here means “the sole right to speak”.

Comment: attention with raps of a small eating utensil against a glass

Comment: If you are not a member of the group "Excuse me" with a slight rising tone at the end would usually work in the UK. If you are a member of the group and you need to make a more or less formal announcement (such as 'they want us to go through to the dining room') you could say "Just a moment", say "Everybody" or even just cough to draw their attention.

Comment: Raise your hand to be recognized by the group or meeting "leader". OR say: "May I have your attention?". Not get.

Comment: A very common way that teachers ask for attention is to say: "Listen up!"

Comment: @Shoe — I wouldn't listen to any teacher that put an unnecessary preposition after "listen".

Comment: @Wendy — Fewer words, not less words. Remember "Less sugar, fewer lumps".

Comment: @David. And the exasperated teacher whose students have ignored several attempts to get them to listen can shout "_Shut!_".

Comment: @Shoe — Don't shout. Don't even ask the students to be quiet.  Just pick on one student and stare at him, then the next. Let them make the decision that they want to be taught.

Comment: "Hey you idiots!  Listen!!"

Answer (score 4):

You could simply shorten it to, "Attention, please".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say, "Excuse me". the expected response is for the group to turn to look at you or say something like "Yes?" or "Hmm?", at which point you have their attention.

> **excuse me**
>   1 Used as a polite apology in various contexts, such as when attempting to get someone's attention, asking someone to move so that one may pass, or interrupting a speaker.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excuse)

It captures the essence of a request for permission to speak (further).

Answer (score -3):

Shouting **silencio** does the trick. It's not as informal as shouting **oye** and it works phonetically because you can emphasise the **o** at the end. Shouting **silence** doesn't work as well, because it may not be heard when the crowd is noisy.

According to [Urban Dictionary's entry of **silencio**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Silencio.):

> The Spanish Word for silence. Used to quiet various size groups of people in a fast effective manner. From Chapelle's Show Season 2, the "Racial Draft 2004."

I looked up that clip from the Chappele's show, but it's not used properly because it's not shouted and the emphasis isn't on the end.

I think the trick to a good silencio shout is taking your time with the first **i** (about 1 second), this draws attention, and emphasising the **o** at the end to show the audience you're serious.

Attribution: "Silencio." Urban Dictionary. Accessed April 18, 2018. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Silencio.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a good clip demonstrating its use. Should anyone come across one, please post the link.